# CSS height not working

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
.dashboard_wrap {
    display:table;
    min-width:100%;
    height:10px;
}
.dashboard_items {
    display:table-row;
    height:10px;
}
.dashboard_items div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    padding:10px;
    height:10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1300px) {
    div.dashboard_items div {
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

but the height isn't working

JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/

Comment: Which height isn't working? How isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the height of the 'row' to be fixed to something like 10px and then have the items within each cell be scrollable. You can't do this with HTML tables and you can't do it with items set to `display: table-cell`.

Floats to the rescue:

```
.dashboard_items div {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* keep the borders from breaking 100% */
    border:1px solid #236FF5;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
}
```

In this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/rN6fu/6/)** I set the height to 40 so you could more easily see the scrolling. Even at 10px, you can use the mouse wheel or equivalent to scroll.

Alternatively, you can put another element inside of .dashboard_items div and set that element to `display: block` and `overflow-y: scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `height` is working. Just remove `padding:10px` and it will work.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/1/)

```
.dashboard_items div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    height:10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/2/)

```
.dashboard_items div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    height:18px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

[**DEMO3**](http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/5/)

```
.dashboard_items div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F36F25;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: i want the padding on there though

Comment: `padding` for all sides?

Comment: yeah? should i do padding just around the left and right ?

Comment: the height still isn't working on your DEMO

Comment: What do you mean `the height is not working` ?. It works, it is set to `10px`;

Comment: Height is definitely working just fine in both demo's above.  When it comes to sizing of elements, height and width by default is calculated separately from padding and border size. For example, a div with width by height of 10px by 10px, that also has a 10px border, will have an actual size of 30px by 30px.

Comment: @user2710234, see the second DEMO.

Comment: check here - http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/4/ - thats not 10px

Comment: @user2710234, that's not my link!

Comment: i know I've just added more HTML

Comment: These are my links http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/2/.

Comment: right... add some more text into the div with line breaks

Comment: and you will see the height is not working

Comment: @user2710234, see another edit.

Comment: still the same - i just added HTML to your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rN6fu/7/

Comment: so the div should be scrolling because it is not high enough for all the text

Comment: Height is working for me in the above demo's just fine... If you want it to scroll just use overflow-y: scroll;